# PHP How to use header statement in this error()

Tags: php

I'm trying to use header function inside error(),i commented all the code that is there in this function and inserted header() but it is not working.

Here is the link http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/article.php/3877766/Web-Developer-How-To-Upload-Images-Using-PHP.htm

If there are no error then an insert statement should execute.How do i do this in the URL code ?

**Update**

```
function error($error, $location, $seconds = 5) 
{ 
   header("Location:test.php");
}

INSERT into table; This query should execute only when there are no errors.How would i do this ?
```

Comment: You're wanting to use header('Location: myurl.php') instead?

Comment: @Wayne Whitty:I use that only.

Answer (score 0):

**Dirty** fix:

```
function error($error, $location, $seconds = 5) 
{

    $urlToRedirect = $location . '?error_message=' . urlencode($error) ;
    header('Location: ' . $urlToRedirect);
    exit;

}
```

A **better** solution would be to create an array for error messages like so:

```
$errorMessages = array(
    'incorrect_login' => 'Incorrect login credentials.',
    'restricted' => 'Restricted page.'
);
```

Then rewrite your error function and get rid of the seconds parameter, since you're no longer using a refresh (personally, I'd get rid of the location parameter as well, so that all error redirects point towards the same page):

```
function error($error, $location) 
{
    $urlToRedirect = $location . '?error_message=' . $error ;
    header('Location: ' . $urlToRedirect);
    exit;
}
```

Then, call the function like so:

```
error('restricted', 'error.php');
```

Then, on the page you want to display your errors:

```
if(isset($_GET['error_message']) && array_key_exists($_GET['error_message'], $errorMessages)){
    echo $errorMessages[$_GET['error_message']];
}
```

Comment: :How do i execute insert query when there are no errors.What should i use in if(??)then insert what should i use in ??

Comment: If you want an insert if there are no errors, you'll need to do your INSERT query BEFORE header('Location: ' . $uploadSuccess);

Comment: :I'm doing it like that inly but if there is any error then it is inserting but it should not insert when there is a error.

Comment: :I mean to say when there is upload error in the form ,my insert query should not work,it should insert only when my upload is successfully and my header is still not working.Can we take this over chat?

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
function error($error, $location, $seconds = 5)
    { 
        header('Refresh: '.$seconds.'; url=' . $location);

    $content .= <<< END

            <html><head>
            <title>Upload error</title>
            </head>
            <body> 
                    <div id="Upload">
                    <h1>Upload failure</h1>
                    <p>An error has occurred: 
                    <span class="red">$error</span>
        The upload form is reloading</p>
        </div>
        </html>
END;

        echo $content;

        exit; 
    } // end error handler
```

Comment: :What does error<>"" does ? can you pls,llok at that link and tell me,how i should use the code ?

Comment: :can you pls look at this link http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/article.php/3877766/Web-Developer-How-To-Upload-Images-Using-PHP.htm and change your code according to that,i did not under stand your code.